# Помогите разобрать код создания ScrollViewer

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Смотрю примеры создания постепенной загрузки элементов ListView разобрал почти весь код кроме одной функции.

```
  private void lstSource_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ScrollViewer viewer = GetScrollViewer(this.lstSource);
    }

  public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj) // эту функцию
    {
        if (depObj is ScrollViewer) return depObj as ScrollViewer;

        for(int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj);i++)
        {
            var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
            var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
            if (result != null) return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Мне бы просто понять в какой строчке что происходит...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Смотрите.

У вас подэлементы, из которых состоит ваш `ListView`, организованы в дерево. Этот код находит при помощи стандартного поиска в глубину первый подэлемент типа `ScrollViewer`, и возвращает его.

```
public static ScrollViewer GetScrollViewer(DependencyObject depObj)
{
    // если текущий объект имеет тип ScrollViewer
    if (depObj is ScrollViewer)
        // закастить его в ScrollViewer и вернуть
        return depObj as ScrollViewer;

    // иначе ищем ScrollViewer среди подобъектов рекурсивно
    // обходим индексы подобъектов 
    for(int i = 0; i < VisualTreeHelper.GetChildrenCount(depObj);i++)
    {
        // получаем подобъект по индексу
        var child = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(depObj, i);
        // запрашиваем рекурсивно у подобъекта, есть ли в его поддереве ScrollViewer
        var result = GetScrollViewer(child);
        // если есть, мы его нашли, возвращаем
        if (result != null) return result;
        // иначе продолжаем поиск в следующем поддереве
    }
    // ничего не нашли - возвращаем null
    return null;
}
```

---

Заметьте, что это достаточно грубый хак: нас обычно не должно интересовать содержимое чужого шаблона. Более чистый путь — применить собственный стиль, в котором поменять шаблон на то, что нужно. Таким образом мы гарантируем наличие в нужном месте нужного элемента (и для упрощения поиска сможем дать ему имя).

Comment: Большое спасибо за разъяснения) Только я не понял про грубый хак, в смысле чужого?...

Comment: @Denisok: Дело в том, что вы не контролируете наличие `ScrollViewer`'а внутри `ListView`. Он может отсутствовать, или их может быть несколько. А если вы контролируете, то вы просто можете дать ему просто имя, и искать по имени.

Comment: Все, понял) Спасибо еще раз

Comment: @Denisok: Пожалуйста.